# How can I look for unique values while having duplicate ids?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, primary-key

I have a table that has ids that repeat. I want an id that has all three values (`TWIX`, `HERSHYS`, and `M&MS`). The values can be on different lines but I do not know how to find the id by using statements that go line by line rather then by groups.

I have tried (in Microsoft SQL server)

```
select *, 
case when 'Hershys' in (Col1, Ccol2) then 1 else 0 as case1,
case when 'TWIX' in (Col1, Col2) then 1 else 0 as case2,
case when 'M&M' in (Col1, Col2) then 1 else 0 as case3
into #candyflags_t1
from table 
    

   select * from #candyflags_t1
   where case1 > 0 and case2> 0 and case3 > 0
```

This does not work due to SQL going line by line. How should I go about either creating flags or querying this in order to find which id group has all three values?

```
+--------------------+----------+
|  ID     |    Col1    | Col2    |
+---------------------+----------+
| L123    |   TWIX     |         |
 +--------------------+----------+
| L123    |  Hershys   |         |
+--------------------+-----------+
| L123    |            |   m&ms  |
+--------------------+----------+
| F143    |            |   m&ms  |
+--------------------+----------+
| F143    |   Snickers | gummies |
+--------------------+----------+
```

In this table I would want to find L123 but not F143.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  If you want the ids that have all three brands:

```
select id
from table t cross apply
     (values (col1), (col2)) v(col)
where col in ('Hershys', 'TWIX', 'M&M')
group by id
having count(distinct col) = 3;
```

`cross apply` is a convenient way of unpivoting the data, so you can deal with one column instead of two.